# Trying to use SQL to reconstruct files from an Opererp 7 postgres db bytea (binary data)

Tags: sql, postgresql, binary-data, openerp-7

I have an old Openerp 7 postgres database, which I'm trying to extract the old invoices.

I've read that they are stored in DataBaseName.ir_attachment.dbdatas

I've manage to come up with this...

```
copy 
(SELECT 
db_datas
FROM
ir_attachment
WHERE
name='Invoice_SAJ_2016_0964_.pdf')
to '/tmp/Invoice.pdf' (FORMAT "binary");
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. It extracts something, but its not openable as a pdf.

I have re-jigged the above and tried other file type .jpg but again no luck.

If I open each file in a text editor each file starts with "PGCOPY" - a clue maybe?

Am I trying something that cannot be done?

Any direct greatly appreciated.

edit...

- Must add, cannot load the db through openerp due to corrupt wkf
  tables
- I'm starting to think openerp add some of there code to the beginning
  of the binary! Maybe I have to do something like [Giulio Marcon
  suggests here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/where-are-document-attachments-stored-529)

Comment: try `copy ... to program 'xxd -r -p > /tmp/Invoice.pdf';` (PostgreSQL >= 9.3) or `copy ... to '/tmp/Invoice.txt'` and then `xxd -r -p /tmp/Invoice.txt > /tmp/Invoice.pdf` in the shell;

Comment: Sadly :( these ideas did not work. However many thanks for your suggestions. Please see edited question above for further thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposedly the pdf is encoded by openerp.

The issue was resolved by using a bit of python code, supplied by Jaime Vasquez on the odoo forum pages.

[Answer is here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/trying-to-extract-a-pdf-file-from-ir-attachment-dbdatas-107167)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the SQL `copy` command adds some extra characters at the beginning and end of the output file. Viewing the output file with NOTEPAD++ shows:

```
PGCOPY
ÿ
NULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULSOHNULNULeDC1{useable file content starts here...
...
...
useable file content ends here}
ÿÿ
```

Open the output file with an editor and try to remove the first characters including `DC1` and the trailing two characters `ÿÿ` (maybe you want to use Notepad++ for this). Then save the output file and open it with the appropriate application.

Please note, that there is no linefeed after `DC1` in the 3rd line - hence simply removing the first three lines will corrupt your output file as your useable content in the file starts directly after the `DC1` character.

Should work, hope to have helped...

Comment: Cheers  Klaus, but failed miserably :(, However thanks for remind me that about the question - please see my answer below